# 跟您请教一个字(Do you know this Chinese word?)

Tags: pronunciation, word

左边一个 至 右边一个各 怎么念 是什么意思？
it would look like 至各

Answer (score 10, accepted):

臵 （U+81F5） [ gé ｜ ㄍㄜˊ ]

From 《康熙字典》:

《集韻》「各額」切，音「格」。與「」同。「至」也。
Same as . It means "to arrive" or "to go to".

又《六書原》徦，俗作臵。
The original or formal form of 徦.

徦 （U+5FA6） [ jiǎ | ㄐㄧㄚˇ ]
1. 至；到。(to arrive; to go to)
2. 來。(to come)
3. 姓。(surname)

Comment: If you cannot see some Chinese characters above, I suggest installing the [Hanazono font, 花園明朝體](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/).

Comment: Most supplemental characters are encoded into Unicode specification, their pronunciations & definitions are provided too, generally, they are encoded in SMP (supplemental multilingual plane), and it can tell us in which page we can find them in a dictionary like Kangxi Dictionary.